# Complex Substitute Beyond 64 Nesting Limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substitution

I am using a nested SUBSTITUE function on several cells with long strings in them and update the SUBSTITUE fx regularly which results in me copying and pasting it to all the cells that need it. Problem is, my SUBSTITUTE list grows longer over time and I'm already at the max 64 levels of nesting.

Is there a way to create a new sheet that has one column of the word to search for and the second to replace it with, and somehow call that sheet as a SUBSTITUTE for each cell that needs it? That way I'm not limited by 64 levels of nesting, and I don't need to copy/paste the formula every time it changes for every cell that uses it.

Or some sort of other non-VBA/macro solution. Thanks

Comment: Yes the function is called `REDUCE()` and is lambda-based. Excel insiders required at the moment.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, i dont know whether it would be right to ask, could you share the function `REDUCE()` --> just for learning.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, as per your request, see the answer. Note how I also used it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363987/9758194) Q&A.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, much thanks for the same.!

Comment: @JvdV Sir, i am using O365 Beta Channel, could you guide where i am going wrong, because it gives me `#NAME?` although i see the `LAMBDA` & `REDUCE` in the functions library.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, it worked perfectly like a charm, amazing really, i have to type it manually again to make it work, `=TRIM(REDUCE(A1,C1:C15,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,""))))`

Comment: @makukhbhattacharya, not sure but for me the `MAP()` function isn't working though available in the menus. I guess it's just the beta-insiders side of things and it's bugged for some.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, later it worked for me, when i typed the same manually, and i am sure there are two reasons why it wasnt working one might be because of some non printable characters because i copied from here and pasted the same in the cell A2 and other one is you need to edit the formula, may be because `SUBSTITUTE` Function is showing like this in the answers you have given  `=TRIM(REDUCE(A1,C1:C15,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUEREN(x,y,""))))`

Comment: I had the Dutch version non-translated. Thanks

Comment: @JvdV Sir aha that's ok, i wasn't aware, sorry for the same. Thank you again for imparting so much valuable knowledge.!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REDUCE()` as it's lambda-based and will iterate over all your substrings you would like to substitute:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=TRIM(REDUCE(A1,C1:C15,LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,""))))
```

Comment: Thanks again!!!

Comment: This solution does not work because I am not an Office Insider.

Comment: The solution does work @darkzero901. It does everything you want. It's just that your version doesn't support it yet. Unfortunate.

Comment: Correct. I use Office 365 Enterprise through my work so I won't have access to the Insider features.