# excel multi substitution in filterxml

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use a very long formula only with substitute before I touch the limit of 64 levels and somebody tell me I can use filterxml but how

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE((C3),"BON",""),"LOR",""),"GAN",""),"bon",""),"gan",""),"bon.",""),"lor.",""),"gan.",""),"ARZ","ARTE"),"ARZ.","ARTE"),"ARZ ","ARTE"),"arz","ARTE"),"arz.","ARTE"),"arz ","ARTE")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the goal here? `FILTERXML()` can **not** return reworked notes, so it can't specifically substitute values from a cell. It does have a 'translate()' function, but I'm unsure if that is helpfull. I'd rather opt for the new lambda helper function `REDUCE()` where you could feed an array to a recursive call on `SUBSTITUTE()`. Best is to show sample data with desired results to further explain your needs.

Comment: [To give you an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70961979/9758194)

Comment: in my excel is no REDUCE. I look for another method because im tired using long long nested SUBSTITUTE. my goal is the same like in your example link, just without using columns