# Excel Replace Text via Another Ranges

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, replace, excel-tables

In column A i have a long text, containing substrings that you can find on another range (column D).
I want to search for the substring and if I find it then replace it with the value in column E.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Also you can refer this solution posted by @JvdV Sir : **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959273/complex-substitute-beyond-64-nesting-limit)** on multiple substituting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula in column B:

```
=LET(mapping, tblMapping,
REDUCE([@text],INDEX(mapping,,1)
        LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,XLOOKUP(b,INDEX(mapping,,1),INDEX(mapping,,2))))))
```

This will also work if there are two or more relevant texts - s. last row

[image]

Don't forget to apply "wrap text" to column B.

EDIT according to question in comments:
You can use this formula to return true / false depending on wether at least one text has been found:

```vb
=REDUCE(FALSE,tblMapping[Text to search],
            LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a=TRUE,a,IFERROR(FIND(b,[@text])>0,FALSE))))
```

Comment: While I'm a big fan of LET, maybe it's easier to read avoiding LET in this case, since the table headers are self explaining:
`=REDUCE([@Text],ListB[Text to search],LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,XLOOKUP(y,ListB[Text to search],ListB[Replace with]))))`. Good solution in case of multiple possible strings to replace in the same text.

Comment: it works pefectly P.b. How would you write a formula in another column that just returns TRUE/FALSE if cell in column 'Text' contains one of the substrings in column 'Text to search'?

Comment: I added the solution to return true/false

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following formula, which is based on your data presented on the screenshot above.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3`

```
=LET(
     a,[@Text],
     b,FILTER(Table2,ISNUMBER(FIND(Table2[Text to search],a))),
     c,INDEX(b,,1),
     d,INDEX(b,,2),
     IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(a,c,d),a))
```

---

Since in one of the cells you are using **line-feed**, hence please remember to use **wrap text**, by hitting <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for the desired result column.

---