# I want to take clear phone numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have phone numbers; I need to get rid of the extra characters and leave only numbers.

[image]

idk i tried all, checked video and other.

sorry if my question stupid

I never used formulas in excel sheets.

Comment: Try the substitute() function - Excel has examples of its use.

Answer (score 3):

Try using <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd> function to substitute multiple values at once.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=REDUCE(A1:A10,{"[","'","(",")","]"," "},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,)))
```

---

The solution is based on the question and answer asked here: Solution provided by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir. Reference link to post: **[Complex Substitute Beyond 64 Nesting Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959273/complex-substitute-beyond-64-nesting-limit)**

---

Another alternative using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=MAP(A1:A10,LAMBDA(x,CONCAT(TEXTSPLIT(x,{"[","'","(",")","]"," "},,1))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=MAP(A1:A2,LAMBDA(s,CONCAT(TOCOL(--MID(s,ROW(1:17),1),3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use Ctrl+H and replace (selection cells only) the unnecessary characters with blank space.

If you want a function, you can use SUBSTITUTE [function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) and use that multiple times to remove the characters you want replaced

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),"[","")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=VALUE(  TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,  IFERROR(  VALUE(  MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)  ),  "")  )  )
```

The `MID` tears apart the input string into single characters. `VALUE` attempts to change each character into a number. Non-numerals will result in an error, so `IFERROR` changes those out for a blank ("").

`TEXTJOIN` then puts all the parts back together. It does not use a delimiter so that there is just a string with nothing new. It ignores all the blanks that `IFERROR` created.

Trick is, you now have a string and that won't be amenable to using a custom number format on to display them in some desired way. But... if the string starts with a 0, you will lose it (or them) if you convert the text result into a number.

But that can be overcome, so one more `VALUE` makes it a number.

The reason you can overcome it is that, unless you have numbers that need a variety of formats and that differ in length, you can just use "0" in the format string as many times as you need numerals. So a "0000-0000-00" string would give "0665-8888-01" fr display, even though the actual leading 0 was lost.